# Height of background imageview not adjusting as per text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing one to one chat. So the text I'm sending is shown on the tableview in the background of an imageview with a gray color. The width is proper but the height isn't adjusting as per the text...

There is a function called configure cell thats called everytime..

```
  func configureCell(_ message: ChatMessage) {

    self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: CGFloat(Constants.Chat.corenerRadius))
    print("messageBackground.awakeFromNib: \(messageBackground.bounds)")
    messageTextLabel.text = message.text?.text
    messageTimeLabel.text = message.information?.composed?.toString(withFormat: Constants.Chat.timeFormat)
    if let image = message.information?.status.image {
      messageStatus.image = image
      if (message.text?.text?.contains("offline"))! {
        print("message.information?.status: \(String(describing: message.information?.status.rawValue))")
      }
    }
  }
```

The function `roundcorners` is given as,

```
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    messageBackground.layer.mask = mask
    messageBackground.clipsToBounds = true
    messageBackground.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    messageBackground.layer.masksToBounds = true
    messageBackground.sizeToFit()
  }
```

If the height of the message is more, this is how it is getting clipped...[image]

What is going wrong here..?

Comment: Did you add your text programmatically or in GUI? I assume you should add some constraints.

Comment: the text typed in the box beside the '+' icon is loaded in the tableview when the right arrow icon to the right (>) is pressed..

Comment: i think there is something wrong with contstraint of background image

Comment: @user308123 I suggest you add some screenshots of your layout settings and constraints

Comment: contraints for the imageview is leading,trailing,top,bottom @DJ-Glock

Comment: i could see that you are setting constraints for image view alone. but the constraints has to be setted for the messageTextLabel as well. that will fix you issue. Note: using UIBazierPath for each cell is costly. which may effect in reducing the 60 FPS 
Hint: You can use UITableViewDimension. that is more often used in chat application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Also, make sure your background view is pinned to the bottom of the cell. Below is a crude example, not sure what your cell layout looks like.
[image]

Here is a tutorial as well showing how to auto resize UITableViewCell 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you are using this properly, it is most likely the constraints of the background view that are causing the issue.

Comment: It is not a good idea to post only link in answer, later the link may not work. Try adding some more information in the answer

Comment: Updated to show constraints. Not much to go off of with question though. Would be nice to see existing layout and tableview implementation.